# Torchlight: What is this purple cloud over my enemy indicating?

Tags: torchlight

Sometimes, I see a purple cloud over my enemies. Then I can't attack them anymore. What is this and how can I avoid that?
[image]

Comment: If you could add a screenshot to your question, that would help in getting you an answer (and also make the question more useful for others)

Comment: Thanks, your provided me with a reason to start gaming again ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have charmed the enemy, and it is on your side (for a while). Check your gear, you probably have an enchantment on your weapon or clothing.

Comment: Yes I have, but it says for 20 seconds only. But this stays forever as long as I can just. At least for more than 5 minutes I checked.

Comment: Maybe a bug in torchlight? Or you have multiple items with charming enchantment?