# what is the green trailing glow on enemies?

Tags: torchlight

What about the green trailing glow above the heads ? It's not going away and I can't attack them with it on and I find no enchantments other than the purple one for making them attack for you. Also I waited approx. 30 minutes before moving on to the next batch of enemies.[image]

Comment: That monster could be charmed. Do you or your pet have the Charm spell?

Answer (score 1):

[Charm spells are displayed in Green](http://torchlight.wikia.com/wiki/Spells_(T1)), so that monster might be Charmed. The [purple enchantment](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/16969/torchlight-what-is-this-purple-cloud-over-my-enemy-indicating) shows their Charmed status, and if you've waited for over a few minutes then it's probably a bug that causes them to remain friendly forever. It's also a bug in Torchlight 2, as shown in [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7VZ8GG_pxJ8).